# Springer manuscript class natbib not showing references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

I can't find a solution anywhere and I am in a hurry :(

MWE:

```
\documentclass[natbib,smallextended]{svjour3}
\begin{document}

 \citep[e.g.][]{rodenbeck2003co} 

 \citet{rodenbeck2003co} 


\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
%\thebibliography{ref.bib}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
@article{rodenbeck2003co,
  title={$CO_2$ flux history 1982--2001 inferred from atmospheric data using a global inversion of atmospheric transport},
  author={R{\"o}denbeck, C and Houweling, S and Gloor, M and Heimann, M},
  journal={Atmospheric Chemistry and Physics},
  volume={3},
  number={6},
  pages={1919--1964},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Copernicus GmbH}
}
\end{thebibliography}{}

\end{document}
```

the results are coming weird

[image]

where they should come looking like the springer format

[image]

Comment: You have to use `\bibliography{ref}`  where you store the bibliography data in a file `ref.bib` where the format of the entries is like what you put inside `\begin{the bibliography}`. Then you compile you LaTeX source file, then you run `bibtex filebasename` and then you compile your source two more times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your TeX file (say ankhi.tex) should look like this:

```
\documentclass[natbib,smallextended]{svjour3}
\begin{document}
\citep[e.g.][]{rodenbeck2003co} 
\citet{rodenbeck2003co} 
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{ankhi}
\end{document}
```

And the bib database file should contain (named as ankhi.bib):

```
@article{rodenbeck2003co,
  title={$CO_2$ flux history 1982--2001 inferred from atmospheric data using a global inversion of atmospheric transport},
  author={R{\"o}denbeck, C and Houweling, S and Gloor, M and Heimann, M},
  journal={Atmospheric Chemistry and Physics},
  volume={3},
  number={6},
  pages={1919--1964},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Copernicus GmbH}
}
```

Please add other bib entries in this file as given above.

Then you need to run the following (`pdflatex` or `latex`):

```
pdflatex ankhi.tex
pdflatex ankhi.tex
bibtex ankhi
pdflatex ankhi.tex
```

This will generate the PDF successfully.

Answer (score 5):

You are making a few mistakes... But since you are in a hurry, see if the following works for you

```
\documentclass[natbib,smallextended]{svjour3}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{rodenbeck2003co,
  title={$CO_2$ flux history 1982--2001 inferred from atmospheric data using a global inversion of atmospheric transport},
  author={R{\"o}denbeck, C and Houweling, S and Gloor, M and Heimann, M},
  journal={Atmospheric Chemistry and Physics},
  volume={3},
  number={6},
  pages={1919--1964},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Copernicus GmbH}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

 \citep[e.g.][]{rodenbeck2003co} 

 \citet{rodenbeck2003co} 


\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{ref}


\end{document}
```

About the mistakes you've made, I think that Guido has already answered.

Also, if you were trying to include your `.bib` file inside your main document, to be extracted during the compilation, you have to use the `filecontents` environment.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem, it takes me a day to find the problem.
It turns out that I accidently add a space in the list while citing several papers.
The correct form is

```
\cite{paper1,paper2}
```

while the wrong form is

```
\cite{paper1, paper2}
```